# Is there a Flutter library that can scan for WIFI networks and connect/disconnect to/from these networks, that works for Android API level 28-30

Tags: android, flutter, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am working on a Flutter app that needs to scan for WIFI networks and be able to connect and disconnect to/from these.

I have tried to use [wifi_configuration](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_configuration) which works with Android 9(API level 28) but not above this.

I also tried using the following libraries, [wifi_iot](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot), [wifi](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi),  which does not seem to support Android 10 and 11.

Do you know if there exist any library that support these actions in Android 9, 10 and 11?

I have also tried to find a Java or Kotlin library that supports these features for the different Android version. I can create a method-channel to communicate to these from my Flutter app, but I have not be able to find any libraries that have support for these different Android version. Are there any libraries/packages in Java/Kotlin that can accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried [Connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) package?

Comment: [flutter_wifi_connect 0.0.7 ](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wifi_connect)

Comment: @AndreyGritsay From my understanding https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity is only able to provide information about whether the device is on mobile or WIFI network. Connecting/disconnecting and scanning for WIFI networks is not supported

Comment: @Daniel Did you find any solution to this issue? I'm using wifi_iot package but it is working only in Android 10 for my case. I need solution for the other versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [wifi_iot](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot). scan, connect & disconnects is working on android 11.

use `WiFiForIoTPlugin.loadWifiList()` for scanning available networks

```dart
// scanning
final wifis = await WiFiForIoTPlugin.loadWifiList();
log("${wifis.map((e) => e.ssid).toList()}");

// connecting
final ssid = "test network";
final res = await WiFiForIoTPlugin.connect(
        ssid,
        password: "12345678",
        security: NetworkSecurity.WPA,
        withInternet: false,
      );
if (res)
  print("connected")
```

Comment: Can you add your code where connect and disconnect to a network found via WiFiForIoTPlugin.loadWifiList()?

Comment: For their class WiFIForIoTPlugin which has the connect() method they have the following deprecated tag: "This is will only work with < Android SDK 26. It could be made to work for >= Android SDK 29, request at https://github.com/alternadom/WiFiFlutter/issues/134."

Comment: @Daniel I used sdk 31 and android 11,  both `loadWifiList()` and `connect()` worked as expected